# Performing where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this client table:

```
+----------+----------+---------+
| cliecode | cliename | deleted |
+----------+----------+---------+
|    00001 | ABC      |         |
|    00002 | DEF      |         |
|    00003 | GHI      | yes     |
|    00004 | JKL      |         |
+----------+----------+---------+
```

And I'm performing a search query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM client 
WHERE deleted ='' 
      AND cliecode LIKE '%$_POST[key]%' OR cliename LIKE '%$_POST[key]%'
```

I want to fetch the `deleted = ''` first before the `like` condition. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

then group your `OR` condition by putting them inside parenthesis,

```
select  * 
from    client 
where   deleted ='' and 
       (cliecode like '%$_POST[key]%' or cliename like '%$_POST[key]%')
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not that good with MySQL yet so thanks kababayan. :)

Answer (score 0):

have you set any defualt value in deleted field?

if not -

then your query should be -

```
select * from client 
where 
deleted is null 
and cliecode like '%$_POST[key]%' 
or cliename like '%$_POST[key]%'
```